# No next button when importing Maven projects in IntelliJ

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, import

I am trying to follow a tutorial on spring boot, first step is to import a maven project in intelliJ, generated by spring initializer, but when I try to do so, I have no next button in the import window, only "finish". And when I click on finish, it does not seem to detect packages. Any idea ?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import from Maven dialog was replaced with single open action and now takes all the defaults without showing any additional dialogs with many various settings: [IDEA-223880](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-223880).

Answer (score 0):

You may check with these guidelines.

1. Just type `mvn install` in the terminal.

or

1. **Settings** --> **Build,Execution,Deployment** --> **Maven** --> **importing**
2. Check the `import Maven projects automatically`

which will enable imports automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed all dependencies were resolved with maven build :) 
Thanks guys !

Answer (score 0):

Just to keep the question complete: In my case IntelliJ was unstable with JDK 12 and I had to use JDK 15. Another thing you might check is whether pom.xml is in the directory (in the past I have accidentally removed the file - type "maven" was displayed but after selecting "Maven" type there was only "Finish" and no "Next").[image: Image showing scenario described above]